# Setting up ajaxterm with apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ajax

I have ajaxterm running in my localmachine. I want to access it from remote machines (virtual machine)

I mainly followed this http://www.tbaumi.de/blog/?p=585 tutor

https://localhost/ajaxterm

```
  Colors   GET   Paste     Connection status:404
```

Here is my httpd.conf file

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
 <Directory  /usr/share/ajaxterm >
        AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        DocumentRoot  /usr/share/ajaxterm
# ErrorLog error_log.log
 #TransferLog access_log.log
 #ServerName 192.168.1.3
</VirtualHost>
```

cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

```
</VirtualHost>                                  
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /ajaxterm http://localhost:8022
ProxyPassReverse /ajaxterm http://localhost:8022


      [Sat Jul 31 17:22:20 2010] [error] [client ::1] ModSecurity: Unable to retrieve   collection (name "global", key "global"). Use SecDataDir to define data directory first.   
[hostname "localhost"] [uri "/ajaxterm"] [unique_id "TFQOdH8AAAEAAE-nKKsAAAAG"]
       [Sat Jul 31 17:22:20 2010] [error] [client ::1] ModSecurity: Unable to retrieve collection (name "ip", key "::1"). Use SecDataDir to define data directory first. [hostname "localhost"] [uri "/ajaxterm"] [unique_id "TFQOdH8AAAEAAE-nKKsAAAAG"]
      [Sat Jul 31 17:22:20 2010] [error] [client ::1] ModSecurity: Unable to retrieve collection (name "global", key "global"). Use SecDataDir to define data directory first. [hostname "localhost"] [uri "/u"] [unique_id "TFQOdH8AAAEAAE-oKZQAAAAH"]
      [Sat Jul 31 17:22:20 2010] [error] [client ::1] ModSecurity: Unable to retrieve     collection (name "ip", key "::1"). Use SecDataDir to define data directory first. [hostname "localhost"] [uri "/u"] [unique_id "TFQOdH8AAAEAAE-oKZQAAAAH"]
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting in your logs ?

Comment: I have added the error log - while accessing ajaxterm.Thanks

Comment: 192.168.1.3 is my local machines current ip address. should i change httpd to localhost instead of 
 ServerName 192.168.1.3

Comment: I tried changint ServerName to localhost but got the same error So i removed Entire ServerName entry and then started again  - current i'm getting errors https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=523051
But they say its harmless warning.

Comment: ADDED CORRECT LOGS NOW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this guide helped. 
http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/

Answer (score 0):

Yeah erm, read your logs. You didn't configure mod_security. `SecDataDir` must point somewhere.